# When is Einstein summation implied by Lorentz indices?

Tags: general-relativity, notation, tensor-calculus

I would like to ask if it is possible to find out whether Einstein summation is used in an equation.

For example,
$$A^{\mu \nu} = 1$$ 
can either mean $\sum_{\mu\nu} A^{\mu \nu}=1$ or $A^{\mu \nu}=1$ for every $\mu\nu$.

Then there can be more complex cases where only one index is summed over. Is it possible to figure out which indices are being summed over?

Comment: Hi Otto. Are you asking how to tell when [Einstein summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) is implied? If so, the Wikipedia link gives a good description. I looked at the book you link but I couldn't see any obvious link between the use of the phrase "not a coordinate tensor" and whether Einstein summation is being used.

Comment: Where does dimensional analysis come in? Each of the terms in $A^\mu B_\mu$ has the same dimension (since they are added), so dimension can't tell you whether the author blundered and meant $A^0 B_0$.

Comment: Ah right, ok the Wikipedia answered my question. @JohnRennie : If you like you can add the answer

Comment: It's also written in the "Notation" section of the book: "Repeated paired dummy indices are summed over, the implicit summation convention. In special and
general relativity, one index of a pair must be up (contravariant), while the other must be down (covariant).
If the space being considered is Euclidean, then both indices may be down."

Comment: You can answer your own question - I think that's much better than the answer in the EDIT in your question.

Comment: I also can't think of a case where anyone would take the sum $\sum_{\mu}\sum_{\nu}A^{\mu \nu}$.  Almost, universally, they are taking the trace of the matrix, which is labeled ${\rm Tr}(A^{\mu \nu})$ or they are contracting it on the metric, $g_{\mu \nu}A^{\mu \nu}$.  The latter thing would usually just be called $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer: if an index appears twice, it implies summation.